# RegEx to divide string by +*-/ and keep delimiter?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl, split

How can I split a string into pieces every time a "/*-+" appears and keep the delimiter? So, have something like

```
10x+4-1
```

turn into

```
10x
+
4
-
1
```

I've tried

```
@left_split = split(/(?<=\+)(?<=\-)(?<=\/)(?<=\*)/, $left_side);
```

I want the delimiter to be placed in its own array [].

However, if something like

```
4(x-3)
```

appears, how do I stop the reg-ex from splitting the 4(x and - 3)?

Comment: provide a complete example along with expected output.

Comment: see [Marpa Enhanced Calculator](https://github.com/choroba/marpa-enhanced-calculator/blob/master/calc.pl).

Comment: Are you trying to parse arithmetic expressions? If so, regular expressions cannot do it. You would need a tokenizer and a push-down stack parser. I suggest you use a CPAN module like Parse::RecDescent for this. https://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RecDescent

Answer (score 3):

It's laudable that you're making an attempt to write a solution to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29868934) but you really will find it extraordinarily difficult.

The way to do this is with a stepwise *tokeniser*, like this. It will ignore any whitespace and also capture any parentheses, and it will stop parsing the string if it hits any invalid character.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = '10x+4-1';

my $tokens = qr{ \+ | \- | \* | / | \d+ | [a-z]+ | \( | \) }x;

while ( $s =~ m{ \G \s* ( $tokens ) }gx ) {
  my $token = $1;
  print $token, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
10
x
+
4
-
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a capture group around the regex used in [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
split(/([+*\/-])/, '10x+4-1')
# ('10x', '+', '4', '-', '1')
```

Or:

```
print join("\n", split(/([+*\/-])/, '10x+4-1'));
```

Prints:

```
10x
+
4
-
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
(?<=[+*\/-])|(?=[+*\/-])
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=[+*\/-])` position where lookbehind match is `+, *, / or -`
- `(?=[+*\/-])` position where lookahead match is `+, *, / or -`

Code: `@left_split = split(/(?<=[+*\/-])|(?=[+*\/-])/, $left_side);`

**Edit:** For restricting to split on strings like `4(x-3)` you can use

```
((?<=[+*\/-])|(?=[+*\/-]))(?!.*?\))
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX2fB9/7)

Comment: Awesome! This works amazingly except that it adds some elements to the array that are only '' For instance, an equation: 3(7x-1)+10x-4+3x=90x+1 Gives an output of 
$VAR1 = '3(7x-1)';
$VAR2 = '';
$VAR3 = '+';
$VAR4 = '';
$VAR5 = '10x';
$VAR6 = '';

Comment: @nat47: For better readability you should use `Dumper` with *references* to arrays, like `print Dumper \@array`